# What's wrong with this SQL query for finding common entries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table video_categories (id, vid_id, cat_id) and i am trying to find number of categories shared by two video entries with the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cat_id`
FROM `vid_categories`
WHERE `vid_id` =1
IN (
SELECT `cat_id`
FROM `vid_categories`
WHERE `vid_id` =2);
```

I keep on getting an empty set result where I am sure that the two videos ive chosen have categories in common.

This is MySQL..any thoughts?

Comment: This should report an error. `AND column IN ....`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cat_id`
FROM `vid_categories`
WHERE `vid_id` = 1 AND 
      `cat_id` IN (SELECT `cat_id` 
                   FROM `vid_categories`
                   WHERE `vid_id` = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      v1.Cat_ID
   from
      Vid_Categories V1
         JOIN Vid_Categories V2
            on V2.ID = 2
           AND V1.Cat_ID = V2.Cat_ID
   where
      v1.ID = 1
```

From query explanation performance, I don't know if this or Sam's answer would perform better... on such a small scale of any anticipated categories, either would be fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cat_id`
FROM `vid_categories`
WHERE `vid_id` /*=1*/
IN (
SELECT `cat_id`
FROM `vid_categories`
WHERE `vid_id` =2);
```

however very strange query, is `vid_id` referensed by `cat_id` ?

please explain what do you need to select ?